# How can I know where has a function been called from?

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to debug some functions in my code. Unfortunately, gdb is not available in the system, so debugging is done, at the moment, by printk messages (it is a linux kernel driver).

There is a function being called with some parameters. I would like to know if it's possible to know who and how called the function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable stack dumping to see the stack and the call trace. You can use the function dump_stack() to print the stack and the call trace on the default console.

Have a look at :

- http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Enabling_Stack_Dumping_in_Linux_Kernel
- http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking-HOWTO/Debugging_Kernel

Answer (score 1):

You can also read code offline by Ctags and cscope.

using cscope f c Function_name in vim， you will get the call trace.

In windows, you can try the Source Insight.

Answer (score 1):

GCC provides the function `__builtin_return_address`.
`__builtin_return_address(0)` should give you the address of the call site, within the calling function. Search for the nearest value in `/proc/kallsyms` to find the function.

Answer (score 1):

Calling dump_stack() in the kernel code is the way to go.